# summing tuples in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 1), (3, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 1)]
```

and I want to sum the right-side of tuples where the left-side is equal, and to put it in another tuples-list, so for the above list i'll get:

```
[(0,2),(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,2)]
```

I tried this:

```
k=0
for i,TCtup in enumerate(wordsMatchingList):
    if wordsMatchingList[i][0]==k:
        TC_matches+=wordsMatchingList[i][1]
        print("k: {} /// TC_matches: {}".format(k,TC_matches)) #for checking
    else:
        groupedWordsMatchingList.append(tuple((k,TC_matches)))
        TC_matches=0
        k+=1
```

but from k=1 it just loop one time less for every k because of the else condition.

thank you

Comment: Did you look at itertools.groupby?

Comment: Are your tuples guaranteed to be in sorted order like this?

Comment: Paul Rooney- I'll look for it now.

Comment: abarnert- yes it guaranteed to be in sorted order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yet another way,

```
t.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) #sort before groupby (required)
g=itertools.groupby(t, lambda x: x[0])
new_l = []
for k,v in g:
    new_l.append((k, sum([x[1] for x in v])))
```

Answer (score 3):

If your tuples are guaranteed to come in order like this—all the `(0, x)`, then all the `(1, x)`, etc.—you can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> xs = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 1), (3, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> groups = groupby(xs, key=itemgetter(0))
>>> ys = [(key, sum(map(itemgetter(1), group))) for key, group in groups]
```

If they *aren't*, but you can sort them (you have a list, not just an arbitrary iterable, and it isn't so huge that log-linear time will be too expensive):

```
>>> groups = groupby(sorted(xs, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))
```

If you can't sort them, you can manually build up the totals as you go:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> totals = Counter()
>>> for k, v in xs:
...     totals[k] += v
>>> ys = list(totals.items())
```

Comment: `e = {}; for k, v in xs: e[k] = e.get(k,0)+v` should work. I also tend to think this will have least complexity as compared to the one with groupby, map, sum and for loop all at once

Comment: @Onyambu That's the same as my last version but with a one-letter variable name for `totals`, and repeating yourself to avoid the use of `Counter`, and missing the last step. Also, if by "least complexity" you mean computational complexity, then yes, as I explained, sorting takes log-linear time; if you've already done it, then the rest of the work is linear, but otherwise, it obviously isn't.

Comment: I am not talking of mine. I am saying your second answer is better than your first answer. Leave alone the code i wrote

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is using a `defaultdict` (from [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) and to iterate the list of tuples.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 1), (3, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 1)]

d = defaultdict(int)

for (u,v) in lst:
    d[u]+=v

# list(d.items()) [(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a library with a `groupby` function. `pandas`, for instance, can be useful

```
>>> s = pd.DataFrame(list_)
>>> s.groupby(0, as_index=False).sum().agg(tuple,1).tolist()

[(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: [(j, sum([i[1] for i in a if i[0] == j])) for j in set([i[0] for i in a])]
Out[5]: [(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 2)]
```

Comment: You are iteraring the whole list for each distinct left elements of a tuple.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, time complexity is O(m*n), but it's easier to read and will do the work for a small sized list as the one posted by op.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 1), (3, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 1)]
[(i,sum([q[1] for q in lst if q[0] == i])) for i in range(lst[-1][0]+1)]
```

gives:

```
[(0,2),(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,2)]
```